# Optional regexp group in freetext

Tags: regex, capture, freetext

I have two kind of text messages - both have a uniformed message code at the beginning but there might be a second match enclosed in ' characters I would need to extract if it is there.

**M0123** Example '**extratext**' with two expected matches.

**M0321** Example without two matches

This matches #1 and captures both groups but does not match #2:

```
^(?<code>M\d+).*(?<extra>'.*').*
```

This matches #1 & #2 but extra group never captured:

```
^(?<code>M\d+).*(?<extra>'.*')?.*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negated character classes should help you out here, like

```
^(?<code>M\d+)[^']*(?:(?<extra>'.*').*)?
```

Transforming the first `.*` into `[^']*` will make it match up to the first quote for your first sample and the whole string for your second.

Notes:

- if in multiline context, you might want to use [^'\r\n] instead to avoid overlapping lines
- you can also use `(?<extra>'[^']*')` if there are always two quotes

Comment: Lovely, many thanks. Using all non-' characters instead of .* is quiet easy to understand, hope I'll remember it too :).